# summing values by rank in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to do a multi-year financial forecast. I need to calculate spending based on rank that year and then re-rank  and calculate spending the next year.

My data frame has the car parts and the cost to fix/replace it with a constrained budget (400 dollars) Once that budget is spent then I can no longer fix anything else that year  but it will be re prioritized for the following year.

In year 1, the budget only covers the transmission,  but in year 2 the transmission is fine and so It is ranked the lowest. How can I run a cumulative sum based on rank up until the budget limit?

```
   df
   Part           Rank(Year 1)     Cost(Y1)   Spend(Y1)   Rank(Y2)   Spend(Y2)

   Transmission        1               400       400         4          0
   Tires               2               400        0          1         400
   Windshield          3               100        0          2          0
   Wipers              4                20        0          3          0
```

Also want to add:

```
    for val in df['Spend']:
        if val.cumsum() >= budget_var:
          val = 0
```

This is how it is right now but I need the sum to be in order of rank.

Answer (score 1):

```
sorted_df = df.sort_values(col_name)
```

Also, I don't think your `cumsum()` is right; you're applying it to individual values in the column, rather than the column as a whole.

Try this

```
df['Spend'] = max(0,df['Cost'].cumsum())
```

Comment: Will I have to make a new data frame every time I calculate for an additional year?

Comment: You could just take a slice and sort that dataframe, but it would be more complicated and there wouldn't be much benefit unless the dataframe is really large. So, for instance:

Comment: sorting_df = df.loc[:,'Rank'].sort_values()


df['Spend'][sorting_df.index] = max(0,df['Cost']

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
>>> df
Out[]:
           Part  Rank(Y1)  Cost(Y1)  Spend(Y1)  Rank(Y2)
0  Transmission         1       400        400         4
1         Tires         2       400          0         1
2    Windshield         3       100          0         2
3        Wipers         4        20          0         3

budget_var = 400

df['Spend(Y2)'] = df['Cost(Y1)'].where(df['Cost(Y1)']
                                         [pd.np.argsort(df['Rank(Y2)'])]
                                         .cumsum()
                                         .where(lambda x: x <= budget_var), 0)


>>> df
Out[]:
           Part  Rank(Y1)  Cost(Y1)  Spend(Y1)  Rank(Y2)  Spend(Y2)
0  Transmission         1       400        400         4          0
1         Tires         2       400          0         1        400
2    Windshield         3       100          0         2          0
3        Wipers         4        20          0         3          0
```

Where:

- `df['Cost(Y1)']` is of course the cost series
- `where(..., 0)` slices the series and return 0 outside slice
- `df['Cost(Y1)']` uses the cost data too
- `[pd.np.argsort(df['Rank(Y2)'])]` slices `Cost(Y1)` to order it according to `Rank(Y2)` order
- `cumsum()` get the cumulative sum of the sorted cost series
- `where(lambda x: x <= budget_var)` is a boolean mask for values less or equal `budget_var`

This way the full cost of each row is displayed in `Spend` if the cumulative sum is less than the budget.
`budget_var = 500` would lead to

```
>>> df
Out[]:
           Part  Rank(Y1)  Cost(Y1)  Spend(Y1)  Rank(Y2)  Spend(Y2)
0  Transmission         1       400        400         4          0
1         Tires         2       400          0         1        400
2    Windshield         3       100          0         2        100
3        Wipers         4        20          0         3          0
```